# How to add marks to Gtk 3 Scale during initialization?

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, gtk3

I'm new to building graphical applications in Python. I started by following the tutorial at https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

My intended application will make extensive use of sliders (Gtk.Scale). To give them a uniform appearance, I'm defining a class MyMeter which inherits Gtk.Scale.

Each slider is meant to have marks. For the sake of example, let's use "X". Here is a screenshot of the intended appearance:

[image]

I accomplished the correct appearance with the following MWE:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk, Gdk

class MyMeter(Gtk.Scale):
    def __new__(cls, maximum, minimum = 0):
        return Gtk.Scale.new_with_range(
            Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
            minimum, maximum, 1
        )
    def __init__(self, maximum, minimum = 0, current = 0):
        super().__init__()
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.value = current

class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(box)
        maximum = 5
        self.meter = MyMeter(maximum)
        for n in range(maximum + 1):
            self.meter.add_mark(n, 0, "X")
        box.pack_start(self.meter, True, True, 0)
        self.show_all()

class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.window = None

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        if not self.window:
            self.window = AppWindow(application = self, title = "Example")
        self.window.present()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

However, notice that `add_mark` is called on the `meter` instance after it is initialized. I want to do this instead:

```
class MyMeter(Gtk.Scale):
    def __new__(cls, maximum, minimum = 0):
        return Gtk.Scale.new_with_range(
            Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
            minimum, maximum, 1
        )
    def __init__(self, maximum, minimum = 0, current = 0):
        super().__init__()
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.value = current
        for n in range(self.maximum + 1):
            self.add_mark(n, 0, "X")
```

Notice how the `add_mark` code is now in the initializer for `MyMeter`. Yet, it results in the following screenshot, where we see the marks have not appeared:

[image]

Why don't the marks appear when I put `add_mark` into the initializer?

How can I initialize MyMeter so every instance of the class shows the intended marks?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. This is the screenshot running it on Fedora 37.

[image: Screenshot running with marks]

I would try to find if there are any customization in your environment theme.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for checking. I don't think I have any customization in my environment theme. Can you pinpoint what I should check? I'm in gentoo with pygobject 3.42.2 and gtk+ 3.24.35

Comment: You can try to use the gtk inspector (https://blog.gtk.org/2017/04/05/the-gtk-inspector/) and veruify if there are any css property hiding the marks. Here have gtk3-3.24.36, almost the same